# runtime error 9 - subscript out of range when copying a seet to a new wrokbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have a simple bit of code as shown below:

```
Private Sub btn_conact_Click()

Dim projectref As String
Dim savelocation As String
Dim projectSearchRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Integer

'set search value (porject key - unique)    
projectref = cmb_Project.Value

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'find the project reference in the tracking spreadsheet

Sheets("Project Tracking").Activate
Set projectSearchRange = Range("A:A").Find(projectref, , xlValues, xlWhole)
LastRow = projectSearchRange.Row
'file directory to save the new workbook in
savelocation = Cells(LastRow, 5).Value    

'template for the contact list
Sheets("Contact List").Activate

Cells(7, 3).Value = projectref
'create new workbook
Set newWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
With newWorkbook
    .Title = "Contact List for Project" & projectref
    .SaveAs Filename:=savelocation & "/" & projectref & "Contact_List.xlsx"
End With

'Windows("Project tracker spreadsheet VBA").Activate
Sheets("Contact List").Copy Before:=Workbooks(projectref & "Contact_List.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1") 'runtime error 9: subscript out of range
Windows(projectref & " Contact_List.xlsx").Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

As can be seen, I am getting a runtime error on the 4th last line of code, which is really a rather important line...

My question is, can anybody see where I could have possibly made a mistake which would cause this error? is successfully creates and saves the new workbook in the specified location, but is just falling over when it tries to copy the required sheet from the old workbook(Project tracker spreadsheet VBA) to the new one created by this code.

Comment: Why have commented out this line `Windows("Project tracker spreadsheet VBA").Activate`? Remove the single quote before this line in your code.

Comment: What is the name of the "old" workbook?  If it is `"Project tracker spreadsheet VBA.xlsm"` then you should use `Workbooks("Project tracker spreadsheet VBA.xlsm").Sheets("Contact List").Copy Before:=Workbooks(projectref & "Contact_List.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, regarding your error, you are already defining and setting the new workbook with `Set newWorkbook = Workbooks.Add`, so why not use it when you "Contact List" sheet between workbooks.

To copy a worksheet between workbooks, you need to fully qualify the `Worksheet` object, `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contact List").Copy Before:=NewWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")`

Second, it's better to avoid using `Activate` when you can work directly with fully qualified `Range`s and `Worksheets`.

**Full Edited Code**:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub btn_conact_Click()

Dim projectref As String
Dim savelocation As String
Dim projectSearchRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim NewWorkbook As Workbook

'set search value (porject key - unique)
projectref = cmb_Project.Value

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'find the project reference in the tracking spreadsheet
With Sheets("Project Tracking")
    Set projectSearchRange = .Range("A:A").Find(projectref, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not projectSearchRange Is Nothing Then '<-- verify that find was successful
        LastRow = projectSearchRange.Row
        'file directory to save the new workbook in
        savelocation = .Cells(LastRow, 5).Value
    Else '<-- find was unsuccessful
        MsgBox "Unable to find " & projectref
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With

'template for the contact list
Sheets("Contact List").Cells(7, 3).Value = projectref

'create new workbook
Set NewWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
With NewWorkbook
    .Title = "Contact List for Project" & projectref
    .SaveAs Filename:=savelocation & "/" & projectref & "Contact_List.xlsx"
End With

' ===== Fixed the error on thie line =====
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contact List").Copy Before:=NewWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
NewWorkbook.Activate '<-- not sure why you want to Activate, but here you go
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: brilliant - worked a treat! thanks for the advice as well :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to insert code in comments so using answers space to guide you.
It appears Windows("Project tracker spreadsheet VBA") is not available. Could be the window text is incorrect. To confirm this. Please insert below code lines where the line has been commented out. This may give you some clue.

```
found = False
  For Each Item In Windows
    Debug.Print Item.Caption
    If Item.Caption = "Project tracker spreadsheet VBA" Then
      found = True
      Exit For
    End If
  Next

  If Not found Then
    MsgBox "Window(Project tracker spreadsheet VBA) -  Not found"
  End If
```